# Inline-block element placement

Tags: html, css

I have three tags with display css attribute set as:
a - inline-block
img - block
span - inline

```
<a id="first">
<img/>
<span>
A first line of tekst
B second line of text
</span>
</a>

<a id="second">
<img/>
<span>
C one line of text 
</span>
</a>
```

My problem is in that situation second element is not in one line with first element when span elements have different size of text.

Why span affects placement of a element?

It looks like last lines of text are in the same line and all other elements depend on it.

Comment: Why are there closed `</img>` tags without any content? Also, the relevant CSS would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure to get it but if you want to avoid line break use CSS `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Also, this looks like everything is in one big line. See http://jsfiddle.net/2Lg3d9qs/

Comment: It isn't empty, i skipped some not important content

Comment: I needed set span as block element and it works well. Can anyone explain why it was kind of one big line before?

Answer (score 0):

It was displayed in a single line because the spans were displaying text inline. However, span is inline by default so it doesn't need to be set to display inline.  Instead of setting span to display as a block, the correct element to use would be div which is a block level element by default.